# How fix "Your app is using dcastalia sdk" rejected app

Tags: android, sdk

I got my App suspended from google play with reason:

> your app is using dcastalia sdk, which causes users to download or install applications from unknown sources outside of Google Play

I can not understand what to change or remove

Here is my app bundle implemenations

```
 implementation files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
    implementation files('libs/unity-ads.aar')
    implementation project(path: ':nativetemplates')
    def room_version = "2.4.3"
    def lifecycle_version = "2.5.1"
    def arch_version = "2.1.0"

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    //firebase
    //implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.1.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:21.3.0'
    //implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.2.0'
    //implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-iid"
    implementation 'com.google.android.play:integrity:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.mediarouter:mediarouter:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework:21.3.0'
    //firebase auth
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:8.0.2'
    // Required only if Facebook login support is required
    // 
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:12.3.0'

    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android:flexbox:0.3.2'                  // google flexible box
    implementation 'com.crystal:crystalrangeseekbar:1.1.3'             // range seek bar
    implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.3.0'
    implementation "android.arch.work:work-runtime:1.0.1"
    implementation 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.orhanobut:dialogplus:1.11@aar'
    // shimmer layout
    implementation 'com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.5.0'
    implementation 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'

    //Room
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-rxjava2:$room_version"
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1"
    //Auto Download and Update
    implementation 'com.github.Piashsarker:AndroidAppUpdateLibrary:1.0.3'
    // ViewModel
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:$lifecycle_version"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    // LiveData
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:$lifecycle_version"

    implementation 'com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'jp.wasabeef:picasso-transformations:2.2.1'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.14.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.14.0'
    implementation 'jp.wasabeef:glide-transformations:4.0.0'
    // retrofit
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.7.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.9.0'
    // stripe
    implementation 'com.stripe:stripe-android:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.stripe:stripe-java:5.36.0'
    implementation 'com.daimajia.easing:library:2.0@aar'
    implementation 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:2.3@aar'
    // download manager
    implementation 'com.mindorks.android:prdownloader:0.6.0'
    implementation 'com.mani:ThinDownloadManager:1.4.0'
    implementation "androidx.tonyodev.fetch2:xfetch2:3.1.6"
    // paypal
    implementation 'com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.16.0'
    // razor pay
    implementation 'com.razorpay:checkout:1.6.18'
    // space bottom navigation view
    implementation 'com.github.armcha:SpaceNavigationView:1.6.0'
    // card slider
    implementation 'com.github.IslamKhSh:CardSlider:0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android:flexbox:0.3.2'
    //OneSignal
    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[4.0.0, 4.99.99]'
    implementation 'com.hootsuite.android:nachos:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:3.2.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
    //admob
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:22.2.0'
    //Facebook audience network
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:6.14.0'
    //mediation
    implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:facebook:6.14.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:applovin:11.10.1.0'
    //implementation  'com.unity3d.ads:unity-ads:4.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:unity:4.8.0.0'
    // exo player
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.14.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-dash:2.14.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:2.14.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-hls:2.14.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:extension-rtmp:2.14.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:extension-cast:2.7.3'
   // implementation 'com.github.HaarigerHarald:android-youtubeExtractor:master-SNAPSHOT'
    implementation 'com.github.HaarigerHarald:android-youtubeExtractor:v2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.cast.companionlibrary:ccl:2.8.4'
    implementation 'com.github.ixiDev:GDPRChecker:v0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.ads.consent:consent-library:1.0.8'
    //bottom navigation
    implementation 'com.github.volsahin:bottomify-navigation-view:1.0.2'
```

updated versions:

compileSdkVersion 34 //33
buildToolsVersion "31.0.0"
defaultConfig {

```
    minSdkVersion 22 //21
    targetSdkVersion 34 //34
    versionCode 45 //42
```

Comment: Probably a dependency of one of the libraries you directly used. Run the gradle Task "app:dependencies" to get the full details of the the dependencies (In Android Studio open the "Gradle" window and browse to app->Tasks->help and then double click on "dependencies). This will then output your full dependency tree and then look for the dcastalia library.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove this dependency

```
implementation 'com.github.Piashsarker:AndroidAppUpdateLibrary:1.0.3'
```